# Trello: When listing boards, what does the "organization" filter do?

Tags: trello

While reading the [API Docs](https://trello.com/docs/api/member/index.html#get-1-members-idmember-or-username-boards) for retrieving a list of Boards I came across a `filter` option named `organization`. I am unsure of what this filter does.

```
https://api.trello.com/1/members/my/boards?
    filter=organization
    &key=[my_key]
    &token=[my_token]
```

Most of the other filter options (closed, open, pinned, public, starred, unpinned) make sense. Though `members` is another vague one.

My best guess is that it means:

```
Show me all boards that belong to an organization
```

Another guess is:

```
Show me all boards that belong to a certain organization
```

But in that case it would need an extra parameter.

What exactly does the `organization` filter do?

Answer (score 2):

Some Trello users have business/company/organisation accounts (we do at Huddle) that allow users to share boards.

Broadly it allows users to be associated and boards shared. It helps with discovery and managability.